# Evitar redireccionamiento de a href

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un enlace con unos parámetros que me agrega un producto al carrito, pero me direcciona y me deja la pagina en blanco.

```
<a id="btn-comprar-mobile" href="/checkout/cart/add?sku=52236&amp;qty=1&amp;seller=1&amp;redirect=false&amp;sc=1" productindex="0" class="checkedimportant">Añadir</a>
```

me gustaria saber si hay una forma de aplicar en el enlace sin que haya redirección?

Intente así, no me direcciona pero tampoco me aplica el enlace.

```
$("#btn-comprar-mobile").click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que lo que denominas *aplicar* el enlace es lo que se conoce como una [petición HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview) (también conocido como AJAX en el antiguo ecosistema de JavaScript y jQuery) usando el [método GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET).

Para realizar la petición no requieres un elemento `a` con `href`, sino un event handler, posiblemente con un formulario. Usando jQuery se puede hacer fácilmente con la función [`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/). Para este caso tendría esta forma:

```js
$("#btn-comprar-mobile").click(function(event){
  // opcional, según el elemento en que ocurra el evento
  event.preventDefault();

  $.get('/checkout/cart/add', {
      sku: '52236',
      qty: '1',
      seller: '1',
      redirect: 'false',
      sc: '1',
      // agregar más parámetros de ser necesario
  })
    .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      // qué hacer si la petición se hizo correctamente
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // qué hacer si la petición falló
    });
});
```